# Sampling from an AR(1) process using normal samples

Tags: r, time-series, sampling, autoregressive

This is probably a very straight forward question but I want to verify how I should sample from an AR(1) process in R using just the `rnorm()` function in R (or any similar function in another language). Say I want to sample 100 samples from the following AR(1) model:

$$
X_t = \rho X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t, \qquad \epsilon_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2_\epsilon).
$$

Then the joint distribution of the vector $(X_1,\dots,X_{100})$ is multivariate Gaussian with zero mean and covariance matrix $\Sigma$, where

$$
BB^T :=\Sigma = \frac{\sigma^2_\epsilon}{1-\rho^2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \rho & \rho^2 & \rho^3 & \rho^4&\cdots\\
\rho & 1 &\rho & \rho^2 &  \rho^3 &\cdots\\
\rho^2 &\rho & 1 &\rho &    \rho^2&\cdots\\
\rho^3 &\rho^2 &\rho & 1 &    \rho&\cdots\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots& \vdots &\ddots&    \vdots\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So I should be able to sample in R using the following:

```
X = matrix(rnorm(100, 0, sigmaeps), 1, 100) %*% B
```

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general approach is fine, but obviously you will need to find the matrix $B$ from your stated form for $\Sigma$.  (Be careful here --- unless you use the *symmetric* square root as $B$ you will need to amend your code to *pre*-multiply by $B$ instead of post-multiplying.)

In any case, if you want to save yourself some time you can use the `rGARMA` function in the [`ts.extend` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ts.extend) where this stuff is already programmed.  This function will produce random vectors from any stationary Gaussian ARMA model, and it can also generate from the conditional distribution if some of the time-series values are given.  Here is an example:

```
#Load the package
library(ts.extend)

#Produce n = 16 time-series vectors from AR(1) process with length m = 30
set.seed(1)
m        <- 30
AR       <- 0.7
MEAN     <- 4
ERRORVAR <- 2
SERIES   <- rGARMA(n = 16, m = m, ar = AR, mean = MEAN, errorvar = ERRORVAR)

#Plot the series
plot(SERIES)
```

[image]

Comment: do you mind explaining a bit more about pre and post multiplying with B, I was planning to take the Cholesky decomposition: $\Sigma = RR^T$ where R is the upper triangular

Comment: The variance rules for linear transforms are $\mathbb{V}(B \epsilon) = B \mathbb{V}(\epsilon) B^\text{T}$ and $\mathbb{V}(\epsilon B) = B^\text{T} \mathbb{V}(\epsilon) B$, so the variance you will get with your formula (using post-multiplication) is $B^\text{T} B \neq B B^\text{T}$.  Unless I am mistaken, the Cholesky decomposition doesn't allow you to swap the order of the parts.